# permission denied when running snap program

Tags: permissions, snap

I downloaded a program called "Simplyfortran", but when I try to run it

```
$ simplyfortran
```

I get the result

```
cannot create directory /tmp/snap.rootfs_SZrcQ1/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32: Permission denied
$ ls -l /tmp/ |grep snap
drwx------ 2 root      me 4096 apr  5 03:21 snap.rootfs_SZrcQ1
```

(me is my username)

How can I run the app? Is there a bugfix comming soon?

Comment: Using `snap info simplyfortran`, the place you want to report your problem would be [here](https://simplyfortran.com/support/). You could also try linking to this question [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/snap), though I'm sure someone from the latter forum who'll have an idea what's up will be along soon anyway :)